# iPhone - image preview class

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is there an easy way to implement an image preview, that is available in the iPhone photos application? I'm talking about the white screen that has many small images and when we click on them, the image becomes full screen.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out ``TTPhotoViewController` from Joe Hewitt's three20 iPhone library.

[Screenshot and English description](http://joehewitt.com/post/the-three20-project/).

[The library itself](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/tree/master).

If you do a search on similar questions here, I think there are one or two with more ideas.